# Generation of assembly file in makefile

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile

I want to modify makefile to generate all the assembly files.
The make file is as follows:

```
# Compiler and Linker

CC           := gcc
LD           := gcc
```

# Standard libraries

CFLAGS_STD   := -g -std=gnu99 \
        -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE \
    -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter 
   LDFLAGS_STD  := -lm

```
# glib

CFLAGS_GLIB  := `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0 gmodule-2.0`
LDFLAGS_GLIB := `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0 gmodule-2.0 gthread-2.0 gobject-2.0`

%.o: %.c %.h
@echo "    [$@]"
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< 


  CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS_STD) $(CFLAGS_GLIB)


LDFLAGS = $(LDFLAGS_STD) $(LDFLAGS_GLIB) 


OPTTREE_OBJS =  opttree.o \
        optsystem.o \
    optmain.o \
    kdtree.o

OPTTREE=./rrtst
OPTTREE_DEPENDENCIES:=$(OPTTREE_OBJS) $(LDFLAGS_COMMON)

all: $(OPTTREE) 


$(OPTTREE): $(OPTTREE_DEPENDENCIES)
        $(CC) -g -o $@ $(OPTTREE_OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) 


clean:
    rm -f *.o *.a *~ $(OPTTREE) $(OPTSYSTEM_TEST)
```

Please help me with this.

Regards,

Pavan

Comment: Pass the `-S` flag to your compiler. And also add `rm -f *.s`.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I am confused with Where should I pass the -S flag?. I am able to generate three assembly files apart from optmain.s by modifying in CFLAGS_STD   := -g -S -std=gnu99 \

Answer (score 1):

Either add

-S

to the end of your CFLAGS=  line, or

CFLAGS += -S

somewhere else in the Makefile, before you hit the target that you want to 
get the assembly output for.